# trino sql convert double to varchar without scientific notation E

Tags: sql, double, precision, presto, trino

Using `Athena version engine 3`:

I'm trying to convert `double precision` value to `varchar` without `E` notation.

Currently:

```
select 
    format('%s', round(abs(0.972) * pow(10, 2 - ceil(ln(abs(0.972)) / ln(10))), 0) / pow(10, 2 - ceil(ln(abs(0.972)) / ln(10))));
```

This will return `0.97` as expected.

But this `format()` function is not supported in Athena.

So I had to cast to `varchar`:

```
select 
    cast(round(abs(0.972) * pow(10, 2 - ceil(ln(abs(0.972)) / ln(10))), 0) / pow(10, 2 - ceil(ln(abs(0.972)) / ln(10))) as varchar);
```

This outputs: `9.7E-1`.

Is there any alternative to `format()`? How can I fix this?

Comment: What engine version are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron its version 3

Comment: Strange, v3 should be based on Trino which has format function

Answer (score 1):

In `Athena`, you can use `printf` function.

```
SELECT
  printf('%.2f', round(abs(0.972) * pow(10, 2 - ceil(ln(abs(0.972)) / ln(10))), 0) / pow(10, 2 - ceil(ln(abs(0.972)) / ln(10))))) AS val;
```